# hyperlink sql absolute path

Tags: php, sql

I stored in sql 1 column with links like: http:www.cnn.com
When I click on the hyperlink created with the code below it adds the url of my searchform before it. Like u12.web.zsxc.com/dir1/dir2/cnn.com

How to solve this problem?

my code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo '<tr><td><a href="'.$row['hyeperlink'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>     </td></tr>';
 }
```

Comment: Can you include the SQL query?

Comment: Also, "http:www.cnn.com" should have "/" too. "http://"

Comment: So what's the expected URL? And what does `echo $row['hyeperlink'];` show you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP part,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 echo '<tr><td><a href="'.$row['hyeperlink'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>     </td></tr>';
 }
```

in your url data should include `http://`

ex:   http://google.com

Comment: Barely beat me.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying what type of array to return, so you're probably getting a numeric array. Change your while loop to:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```